# How to use router-link inside of select option dropdown in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```js
a.vue

<template>
  <div>hi i am component 1</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "a",
};
</script>


b.vue

<template>
  <div>hi i am component 2</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "b",
};
</script>
```

```css
const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: "history",
  routes: [
    {
      path: "/a",
      name: "a",
      component: a
    },
    {
      path: "/b",
      name: "b",
      component: b
    }
  ]
});
```

```html
<template>
  <div class="select">
    <select name="format" id="format" v-on:change="changeRoute($event)">
      <option selected>Settings</option>
      <option value="">a</option>
      <option value="">b</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  methods: {
    changeRoute(e) {
      this.$router.push("/a" + e.target.value);
      // this.$router.push("/b" + e.target.value); not working....
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

How to route to another component, When value select from dropdown in Vuejs using router link.

At present issue is, I am able to redirect to component using router-link, By setting the click event in the select.

Inside select, I have two options called "hello", "hlll". Where for both things it is navigating to same page. But I need to set the different component for different option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issues with the code.

**App.vue**

- You have not added `<router-view></router-view>` in your `App.vue` to hold the routing section

**HelloWorld.vue**

- You have not used `value` for the `options` in select. You shoulld use values as `a` and `b`.

**Template**

```
<select name="format" id="format" v-on:change="changeRoute($event)">
  <option selected>Settings</option>
  <option value="a">a</option>
  <option value="b">b</option>
</select>
```

And from the component you can listen to change event and navigate like.

```
methods: {
  changeRoute(e) {
    this.$router.push("/" + e.target.value);
  },
},
```

Since you have set the value for each option you will have a valid value for `e.target.value` inside the change event.

[**Working Fiddle**](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-select-dropdown-route-forked-3dld4?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue:38-231)

Answer (score 1):

You can create data object with your routes, add them to select , and route on selected accordingly:

```js
const Home = {
  template: '#home',
  data() {
    return {
      links: [{name: 'hello', link: 'mycomp'}, {name: 'hllll', link: 'othercomp'}],
      selectedLink: null
    }
  },
  methods: {
    changeRoute() {
      this.$router.push(this.selectedLink);
    }
  },
}

const Component1 = {
    template: '#component1'
};

const Component2 = {
    template: '#component2'
};

const routes = [
    { path: '', component: Home },
    { path: '/mycomp', component: Component1 },
    { path: '/othercomp', component: Component2 }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
    routes
});

new Vue({
    router
}).$mount('#app');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router"></script>
<script type="text/x-template" id="home">
  <div>
    <h2>Home</h2>
    <div class="select">
      <select name="format" id="format" v-model="selectedLink" @change="changeRoute">
        <option :value="''" selected disabled>select link from below</option>
        <option v-for="(link, i) in links" :key="i" :value="link.link">
          {{ link.name }}
        </option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</script>

<script type="text/x-template" id="component1">
  <div>
    <h2>mycomp</h2>
    <router-link to="/">Home</router-link>
  </div>
</script>

<script type="text/x-template" id="component2">
  <div>
    <h2>othercomp</h2>
    <router-link to="/">Home</router-link>
  </div>
</script>

<div id="app">
    <h1>routing with select</h1>
    <router-view></router-view>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `$event` to the change event handler then use that parameter in router link push method :

```html
  <select name="format" id="format" v-on:change="changeRoute($event)">
```

```js
  methods: {
    changeRoute(e) {
      this.$router.push('/'+e.target.value)
    }
  }
```

Comment: Yes I have added $event. But individually I am not redirecting.  In console it is printing as */hello hlll* (i.e, both option values).  and even if i give like  this.$router.push('/mypage'+e.target.value) it is giving me blank page.

in routing file do i need to change any?

Comment: it should be `this.$router.push('/'+e.target.value)`